# Convert const array in function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to transform the "const itemsProject" below into a "function ItemsProject" with the same return?

```
function onClick(e, item) {}

const itemsProject = [
 {
  name: 'companies',
  label: translate('sidebarProjectCompanies'),
  Icon: CompanyIcon,
  path: '/project/:id/companies',
  onClick,
 }
 {
  name: 'currencies',
  label: translate('sidebarProjectCurrencies'),
  Icon: CurrencyIcon,
  path: '/project/:id/currencies',
  onClick,
 }
];

export default itemsProject;
```

I thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean: `const itemsProjectFunction = () => itemsProject`

Comment: Why do you need a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data from a function and export it, you can use the following code:

```
function onClick(e, item) {}

function itemsProject() {
  return  [
   {
    name: 'companies',
    label: translate('sidebarProjectCompanies'),
    Icon: CompanyIcon,
    path: '/project/:id/companies',
    onClick,
   }
   {
    name: 'currencies',
    label: translate('sidebarProjectCurrencies'),
    Icon: CurrencyIcon,
    path: '/project/:id/currencies',
    onClick,
   }
 ]
};

export default itemsProject;
```

Use it in other files as:

```
import itemsProject from "/path/of/file";


itemsProject();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was returning the wrong function

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function and return the same array.

```
function onClick(e, item) {}

function itemsProject() {

 return [
    {
       name: 'companies',
       label: translate('sidebarProjectCompanies'),
       Icon: CompanyIcon,
       path: '/project/:id/companies',
       onClick,
     }
     {
       name: 'currencies',
       label: translate('sidebarProjectCurrencies'),
       Icon: CurrencyIcon,
       path: '/project/:id/currencies',
       onClick,
     }
   ];
}
```